# Bindy paddingChar

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

In my Bindy model I would like to set a paddingChar on one field. I saw in the documentation that with a @Fixed-length record I can add a paddingChar attribute but with a @CsvRecord it seems not to be the possible ?

This code doesn't pad field mandant with "0":

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ";", generateHeaderColumns=true)
public class Unity{

@DataField(pos = 1, length = 3, paddingChar = '0')  String mandant;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html), you could use the `pattern` attribute for `Double`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Short`, `Long`, and `BigDecimal` fields. The format is defined according to [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
@DataField(pos = 1, pattern = "000")
Float mandant;
```

**EDIT:**

`pattern` is ignored (at least for Camel 2.13.1), if the locale is not set (a kind of a bug or at least an undocumented feature...). Thus, do the following:

```
final BindyCsvDataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(Unity.class);
bindy.setLocale(Locale.US.getISO3Country());
```

**EDIT:**

I opened a Jira issue as I think this should be fixed: [CAMEL-7578](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7578)

**EDIT:**

[CAMEL-7578](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7578) is fixed for Camel versions 2.12.5, 2.13.3, and 2.14.0.